# How to create index on on SQLAlchemy column_property?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy with an SQLite engine, I've got a self-referential hierarchal table that describes a directory structure.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Index
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property, aliased, join
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Dr(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'directories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('directories.id'))
```

Each Dr row only knows it's own "name" and its "parent_id". I've added a recursive column_property called "path" that returns a string containing all of a Dr's ancestors from the root Dr.

```
root_anchor = (
    select([Dr.id, Dr.name, Dr.parent_id,Dr.name.label('path')])
    .where(Dr.parent_id == None).cte(recursive=True)
)

dir_alias = aliased(Dr)
cte_alias = aliased(root_anchor)

path_table = root_anchor.union_all(
    select([
        dir_alias.id, dir_alias.name,
        dir_alias.parent_id, cte_alias.c.path + "/" + dir_alias.name
    ]).select_from(join(
        dir_alias, cte_alias, onclause=cte_alias.c.id==dir_alias.parent_id)
    ))
)

Dr.path = column_property(
    select([path_table.c.path]).where(path_table.c.id==Dr.id)
)
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
"""
-----------------------------
| id |   name   | parent_id |
-----------------------------
|  1 | root     | NULL      |
-----------------------------
|  2 | kid      | 1         |
-----------------------------
|  3 | grandkid | 2         |
-----------------------------
"""
sqllite_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=sqllite_engine)
session = Session()

instance = session.query(Dr).filter(Dr.name=='grandkid').one()
print(instance.path)
# Outputs: "root/kid/grandkid"
```

I'd like to be able to add an index, or a least a unique constraint, on the "path" property so that unique paths cannot exist more than once in the table. I've tried:

```
Index('pathindex', Directory.path, unique=True)
```

...with no luck. No error is raised, but SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to register the index, it just silently ignores it. It still allows adding a duplicate path, e.g.:

```
session.add(Dr(name='grandkid', parent_id=2))
session.commit()
```

As further evidence that the Index() was ignored, inspecting the "indexes" property of the table results in an empty set:

```
print(Dr.__table__.indexes)
#Outputs: set([])
```

It's essential to me that duplicate paths cannot exist in the database. I'm not sure whether what I'm trying to do with column_property is possible in SQLAlchemy, and if not I'd love to hear some suggestions on how else I can go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think unique index should suffice, in class `Db`

```python
__table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('parent_id', 'name'), )
```

Comment: There's just one edge case, though it's debatable if it's an issue: it is possible to insert another root, since the unique constraint does not catch another `NULL, 'root'`. Perhaps if root node were also self referential instead of `NULL`?

Comment: ...Or maybe some hacky partial unique index to enforce single root?

Comment: Something like `Index('dir_single_root_idx', text("(1)"), unique=True, postgresql_where=Directory.parent_id == None)`.